# Removing duplicate values in column with added unique constraint

Tags: sql

I have a table with a displayName column that I have added a "unique" constraint to.  I am trying to write a migration that will set any non unique displayName to null, leaving only the displayName with the lower User Id as is.  Here is my query:

```
UPDATE "User" SET "displayName" = NULL
            WHERE id IN (SELECT id,
                        FROM (SELECT id,
                                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY "displayName" ORDER BY id) AS rnum
                              FROM "User") t
                        WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

When I attempt to run the migration I am getting back "error: syntax error at or near "FROM"".

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help convey what you are using to do.

Comment: `,` after id in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write this as:

```
UPDATE "User"
    SET "displayName" = NULL
    WHERE id > (SELECT MIN(u2.id)
                FROM "User" u2
                WHERE u2."displayName" = u."displayName"
               );
```

Whatever database you are using, this should also be able to take advantage of an index on `"User"("displayName", id)`.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use CTE or Sub-Query, something like this....

```
WITH X AS 
(
SELECT id
     , [displayName] 
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY [displayName] ORDER BY id) AS rnum
FROM [User]
)
UPDATE X 
 SET [displayName] = NULL
WHERE rnum > 1
```

OR

```
UPDATE X
 SET [displayName] = NULL 
FROM (
        SELECT id
             , [displayName] 
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY [displayName] ORDER BY id) AS rnum
        FROM [User]
     ) x
WHERE rnum > 1
```

And on a side note , a unique constraint on a display name really :S ....

Comment: Boss's orders.  Definitely wasn't my idea.

Comment: Note that square brackets are invalid in an SQL identifier. And the question is only tagged with `sql` not a specific DBMS product (and the question also uses standard double quotes)